# Multiple heroku subdomain pointing the same custom domain

Tags: deployment, heroku, dns, subdomain

Is it possible setting multiple heroku subdomains like the following :

```
mydomain.heroku.com

one.heroku.com
two.heroku.com
three.heroku.com
four.heroku.com
```

to point to custom domain mydomain.com ?

```
mydomain.com

one.mydomain.com
two.mydomain.com
three.mydomain.com
four.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to have multiple heroku applications to do this - if this is really what you want to do.

However, if you have myapp.heroku.com you can add the wildcard custom domain addon to a single application which will make your application listen on *.mydomain.com - so therefore anything.mydomain.com would come through to your application where you can then deal with it in your code.